# mySQL query optimisation, range/composite index/group by

Tags: mysql, optimization

The basic form the the query is:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(impressions) as impressions, SUM(clicks) as clicks, SUM(cost) as cost, SUM(conversions) as conversions, keyword_id FROM `keyword_track` WHERE user_id=1 AND campaign_id=543 AND `recorded`>1325376071 GROUP BY keyword_id
```

It seems that I can either index say user_id, campaign_id and keyword_id and get the GROUP BY without a file sort, although a range index on the recorded is really going to more aggressively cut down on rows, this example has a big range but other queries have a much smaller time range.

Table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keyword_track` (
`track_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`adgroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`recorded` int(11) NOT NULL,
`impressions` int(11) NOT NULL,
`clicks` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`conversions` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_cpc` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
`quality_score` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`avg_position` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`track_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

I have left any keys I currently have out of that. Basically by question is what would the best way be to get in index on the range which still indexing at least the campaign_id and ideally not needing to filesort (although that might be an acceptable tradeoff to get a range index on the recorded time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best index for you in this case is composite one `user_id + campaign_id + recorded`

Though this will not help to avoid filesort as long as you have `>` comparison with `recorded` and `group by` field that isn't included in the index at all.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have range constraint and order by constraint on different attributes of a table, we can either take the advantage of the fast filtering or fast ordering for result set but not BOTH.

My answer is...
If your range constraint really cut down huge number of records and result a small set of rows out, better index to support the range constraint. i.e (user_id, campaign_id, recorded)

if not, i mean if there are really big number of rows even after the range condition validated and are supposed to be sorted, then go for for an index that support ordering.
i.e(user_id, campaign_id, key_id)

To better understand this, have a look at the below link where the same thing is explained very clearly.

http://explainextended.com/2009/04/01/choosing-index/

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't really grasp before how the range would prevent further parts of the index from being ordered.